# How do I get the predicted labels from a model.predict function from Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I have built a LSTM model using Keras library to predict duplicate questions on the Quora official dataset. The test labels are 0 or 1. 1 indicates the question pair is duplicate. After building the model using `model.fit`, I test the model using `model.predict` on the test data. The output is an array of values(probabilities) like below:

```
 [ 0.00514298]
 [ 0.15161049]
 [ 0.27588326]
 [ 0.00236167]
 [ 1.80067325]
 [ 0.01048524]
 [ 1.43425131]
 [ 1.99202418]
 [ 0.54853892]
 [ 0.02514757]
```

I am only showing the first 10 values in the array. I don't understand what do these values mean and how do I compare it against the test labels to calculate the test accuracy. I want the model to output the binary predicted values as 0 or 1 rather than the probabilities. Please refer the last section of my code below:

```
sequence_1_input = Input(shape=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,), dtype='int32')
embedded_sequences_1 = embedding_layer(sequence_1_input)
x1 = lstm_layer(embedded_sequences_1)

sequence_2_input = Input(shape=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,), dtype='int32')
embedded_sequences_2 = embedding_layer(sequence_2_input)
y1 = lstm_layer(embedded_sequences_2)

merged = concatenate([x1, y1])
merged = Dropout(rate_drop_dense)(merged)
merged = BatchNormalization()(merged)

merged = Dense(num_dense, activation=act)(merged)
merged = Dropout(rate_drop_dense)(merged)
merged = BatchNormalization()(merged)

preds = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(merged)


########################################
## train the model
########################################
model = Model(inputs=[sequence_1_input, sequence_2_input], \
        outputs=preds)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
        optimizer='nadam',
        metrics=['acc'])



hist = model.fit([data_1_train, data_2_train], labels_train, \
    validation_data=([data_1_val, data_2_val], labels_val, weight_val), \
    epochs=200, batch_size=2048, shuffle=True, \
    class_weight=class_weight, callbacks=[early_stopping, model_checkpoint])


preds = model.predict([test_data_1, test_data_2], batch_size=8192, 
verbose=1)
preds += model.predict([test_data_2, test_data_1], batch_size=8192, 
verbose=1)
preds /= 2
print(type(preds))
print(preds[:20])
print('preds.ravel')
print(preds.ravel())
```

Comment: What is the final layer in your model? Are you using some sort of softmax?

Comment: @ZiyadEdher Please refer my update post, I have added the last section of the code for reference

Answer (score 1):

As you say, your output is a `np array` with probabilities. You can convert it to binary labels by doing for example `(model.predict(X) > 0.5).astype(int)`

Comment: The values are in the range of 0 to 2. So values greater than 0.5 will be treated as 1 and vice versa?

Comment: They are between 0 and 2 because you add them together in the final section of your code. The final activation function of your model is `sigmoid` so your model will always spit out values between 0 and 1.

Comment: I get it now, so is there any other way to define the activation function to output binary classification values?

Comment: You do not want it to do that. Discrete output values are very detrimental to the training of the network (you basically will not be able to take a gradient). When predicting you can just round if you really need to.

Comment: Not out of the box, you could integrate it into your network but be aware that the model is trainable with the crossentropy loss just because it does not predict binary values. It's a small step to convert them afterwards with the line of code above.

Answer (score 0):

Artificial neural networks are probablisitc classfiiers, so your output is absolutly fine. It´s just the probability to belong to your target label.

In addition one interesting fact is that 0.5 is maybe not the offet you want to use. It depends on, how important true-positives and false-positives are in your task. You can take a look at the [ROC Curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic) to find the optimal offset.

Comment: Yeah, even I am not sure if 0.5 should be used as a threshold to classify the labels as 0 or 1. I wanted to do it because I need to plot a confusion matrix for which i need true-positives and false-positives.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing your activation function to softmax in your last layer or you can make your own softmax function and pass your output to that function. Here's an example for a custom softmax function

```
def softmax(x):
    return np.exp(x) / np.sum(np.exp(x), axis=0)
```